# why display :inline not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make a simple web page in which text field and button are in horizontal position I used **display:inline** it is not working why here is my code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/G8mp53rQlF562hEkgmgT?p=preview

when user scroll a input field and button present .they should be in horizontally as show in image [image]

- Please ignore red circle .I need input and button field should be horizontally .
- Secondly When user click menu option ("-") in top right it open menu option the scroll the text .text come over the menu .Text should come below menu

  ```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ionic']);
  //myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
  function MyCtrl($scope, $http,$window) {
      $scope.back={
          height:$window.innerHeight+ "px"

      }
      $scope.obj={
          height:$window.innerHeight/2+$window.innerHeight/3+ "px",
          overflow:"auto" ,
          overflow:"scroll"
      }
      $http.get("menu.json").success(function (data) {
          $scope.menu = data;
      }).error(function () {
          alert('error')
      })
  }
  ```

Comment: ok  but what is solution ?

Comment: Two suggestions: Learn CSS Specificity (try not to use !important) and its doggone difficult to troubleshoot CSS / JS issues using Plunker.  Its hard to get the big picture there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For button in same line as email address input field, the problem is the width of the email input field is the entire width of the .email_row

Try:

```
.email_row input {
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #3C86D7;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 80%;    <-- Add one line to CSS file
}
```

Ouch, the menu hamburger icon appears to be an ionic / angular.js thing, and not a straight bootstrap implementation.  And the Plunker Download is missing a few things, so I can't get an accurate representation of what's going on on my localhost.  Sorry.  I will say it seems to be working very well in plunker (Chrome with dev tools off, on an Apple OS)

Update: Oops. I now understand the menu thing.  I think you just need to add a higher Z-index ranking to the menu in deployed mode. If you didn't want to see the scrolled text at all thru the menu, you could just add a solid background color.  My favorite is to use a background color with .5 opacity.

```
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 .display_menu{
    z-index:  999;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: I  already increase the z index but not work ..please check on your end